# Combine strings and arrays into JSON properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

I've fetched some data from XML document and assigned them into three variables. Root element name, array which contains all the names of root's children and second array with length of those children sub-nodes. I want to convert those variables into the JSON object in this way:

```
{ "root_name": {
         "childName[0]": "lengthSubNodes[0]",
         "childName[1]": "lengthSubNodes[1]",
         "childName[2]": "lengthSubNodes[2]",
}
```

with this function:

```
function XMLtoJSON(rootName,childNames,childNumbers){
            var xmlObject = {}
            xmlObject[rootName] = {}; 
            for(var i = 0; i < childNames.length; i++ ){
                xmlObject[rootName][childNames[i]] = childNumbers[i];
            }

        }
```

Everything works fine. However when it comes to XML document with many root's children with the same name and length they appear just once like this:

```
{ "catalog": {
         "book": 6
}
```

and should look like this:

```
{ "catalog": {
         "book":6,
         "book":6,
         "book":6
}
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't think you can have redundant keys in the same parent attribute of the object - is there a way you can give them a unique key value?

Comment: We are going to need to know *how* your want this "fixed". As  SachiDangalla stated, you can not have duplicate keys. What do you want done with the additional data? One possibility would be to create an array with the values. But, **you** need to figure out what you want and tell us.

Comment: Do you mean "Javascript object" and not JSON?  JSON is a string with a specific form buts it is still a string not a complex object as you describe...

Comment: Your three "book" should be an array perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple keys of the same name under one parent. Also, nodes in xml have an order, which is lost under a js map. So if you want a xml to json utility, you need to create yourself a json schema. Here is a simplistic example:

```
{
    name:      "catalog",
    value:     null,
    children: [
        {
            name: "book",
            value: 6
        },
        {
            name: "book",
            value: 6
        },
        {
            name: "book",
            value: 6
        },
    ]
}
```